# Ignore long lines in silversearcher

Tags: ag

Right now I am using:

```
 ag sessions --color|cut -b1-130
```

But this will cause color artifacts if the search match is cut bu the `cut` command.

Silversearcher has this in the docs:

```
   --print-long-lines
          Print matches on very long lines (> 2k characters by default).
```

Can I change **2k** to something else? (120 for me, because honestly never in any of the code I work with the real code is longer than that).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Very strangely, the documented `--print-long-lines` actually does nothing at all, yet there is a working switch for this: `-W NUM / --width NUM` which is not documented at all. See https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/pull/720

Comment: Ubuntu's version of ag (version 0.31.0) does not support it yet.

Comment: `--width` is now documented and supported in Ubuntu's version of ag.

Comment: Hmm, in my Ubuntu 18.04, `ag` v 2.1.0, `-W | --width` both work, but not listed in the `man` page ... lol.  TY

Answer (score 2):

I can think of three options:

1. Just print the result of your search instead of the whole line, using the -o option: `ag --color -o`
2. Use less instead of cut which nicely chops long lines at the screen size's width using the -S option (chop long lines) and the -R option (to deal with the color escape sequences): `ag --color <pattern> | less -R -S`
3. Use something like sed or awk instead of cut: `ag --color <pattern> |sed -E "s/(.{$COLUMNS}).*$/\1/"`

Which will cut the returned line at the limit of your screen size. Of course, if you're determined to chop at 120 columns, you can: `ag --color <pattern> |sed -E "s/(.{120}).*$/\1/"`

This last option doesn't prevent the possibility of chopping in the middle of a color escape sequence; if you're really hellbent, you can modify the sed search pattern to ignore color escape sequences -- already answered on SO. That said, I don't see the purpose of doing this given the easiness and correctness of option 1 above.

Comment: The `-o` argument is what I really need after I asked this question on google

Answer (score 1):

```
ag --width 400 string dir/

# In .bash_aliases (s is for short)
alias ags='ag --width 400'
```

Ignores lines longer than 400 chars.